# face_recognition python operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror, face-recognition

fellows

Googled before decided to ask by myself. Trying to recieve true or falls, but unfortunately recieving an error. Doing as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz25xxF_AVE says

My code:
`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import os

path = 'ImageAttendance'
# создаем список файлов
myList = os.listdir(path)
images = []
classNames = []
print(myList)

# берем имя под каждый файл по порядку
for cl in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')
    images.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])
print (classNames)
# ищем все расстояния на всех фотках и составляем список
def findEncodings(images):
    encodeList = []
    for img in images:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)
        encodeList.append(encode)
    return encodeList

# создаем список энкодинга всех известных нам людей в базе
encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
print(len(encodeListKnown))
print('Encoding complete')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgS = cv2.resize(img,(0,0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    
    facesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    encodesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, facesCurFrame)
    
    
    for encodeFace,faceLoc in zip(encodesCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
        print('encoding')
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(np.array([encodeListKnown], dtype=object),np.array([encodeFace],dtype=object))
        faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance([encodeListKnown], encodeFace)
        print(faceDis)
```

`recieving:`

```
['face.jpg', 'original.jpg', 'Verc.png', 'test.jpg']
['face', 'original', 'Verc', 'test']
4
Encoding complete
encoding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/verc/Документы/Python/FaceRecognition/AttendanceProject.py", line 46, in <module>
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(np.array([encodeListKnown], dtype=object),np.array([encodeFace],dtype=object))
  File "/home/verc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 226, in compare_faces
    return list(face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding_to_check) <= tolerance)
  File "/home/verc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 75, in face_distance
    return np.linalg.norm(face_encodings - face_to_compare, axis=1)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,4) (1,128) 
[Finished in 10.8s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', '/home/verc/Документы/Python/FaceRecognition/AttendanceProject.py']]
[dir: /home/verc/Документы/Python/FaceRecognition]
[path: /home/verc/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

`
Really appreciate your attention

Tried to use without np.array, w/o [] and dtype=object :c

Answer (score 0):

Found solutions by watching array i've created. As a original image take bright images guys.
The issue is when we encode images with improper light on your face, the method face_encoding returns an empty list and when you compare this with that new image's encoding this error occurs... this might even occur in the reverse case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).